# Handle Error when the server is off in react js (TypeError Failed to fetch)

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, crash-reports, redux-saga

I need to show error in a dialog stating the server has stopped whenever the server crashes or server gets shut down. 
I as console log my error in request as below:

```
export default function request(url, options) {
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON).
    catch(error => {
      console.log("error",error)
      throw error;
    });
}
```

the console is :

```
TypeError Failed to fetch
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `navigator` in you code in order to check if user is offline nor user can't connect to your WebService like below:

```
//if there was a problem with server
if(navigator && navigator.onLine) {
  throw {
    code: 'SERVER_CONNECTION_PROBLEM',
    message: 'Server connection failure...'
  }
} else { // if there is a problem with internet
   throw {
     code: 'INTERNET_CONNECTION_ERROR',
     message: 'there is a problem with your INTERNET, god damn it...'
   }
}
```

Comment: Can I just know the status code in each situation here?

Answer (score 0):

You can check error status e.g. `error.status` and do

```
if(error.statusCode === 503){ // or status code which your server send
 // do something 
}
```

Comment: but I can't get the status code, the server is not sending me status code as the server status is failed here.

Comment: Please share error object. You can also ask server guy to send status code

Comment: "TypeError Failed to fetch", this is only the error I get as I console the erro, which is actually the type object

Answer (score 0):

There is library called **react-offline.**
which used in detect your network is in work or not.

After proper implementation it should be work, it shows offline page which you created when your network goes down...
**link is here :** *https://openbase.com/js/react-offline/documentation*

[Click here for documentation][1]
[1]: https://openbase.com/js/react-offline/documentation

**code example :**

```
<Offline
    render={() => {
        return (
            <div>"I take precedence over any function as child component."</div>
        );
    }}
>
    {() => {
        return <div>"I will not render."</div>;
    }}
</Offline>
```

Comment: import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Offline from "react-offline";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Offline
        onChange={({ isOffline, isOnline }) =>
            console.log({ isOffline, isOnline })}
    >
    </Offline>,
    mountNode
);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Offline
        onChange={({ isOffline, isOnline }) =>
            console.log({ isOffline, isOnline })}
        render={({ isOffline, isOnline }) => {
            return isOffline ? <div>I am offline</div> : <div>I am online</div>;
        }}
    />,
    mountNode
);